# Issues while transferring data from one scene to another in corona

Tags: android, iphone, lua, coronasdk

I am transferring data from one Lua file to another file, and is working fine. There are two Lua files: one is from which the user has selected one of the options and that options will be transferred to another Lua file, but the issue is I want to purge the second scene and then reload it and want that the option which user has chosen on the option screen must be there without reloading the option screen, sample code which I am using is given below. Please help to solve it... thanks.

```
local options

function scene:enterScene(event)
{
    local group = self.view
    options = event.params.options
}

storyboard.purgeScene("scenes.ReloadScreenloadScreen")
local options = 
{
    effects = "fade",
    time = 1000,
    params =
    {
        option=_options
    }
}

storyboard.gotoScene("scenes.ReloadScreenloadScreen", options)
```

Comment: https://github.com/NoRuBal/canny/blob/master/lib/ego.lua~

Answer (score 0):

you can use _G.variableName to set a global variable and access with in all scenes

```
_G.option = _option
```